# Is it possible to make ImageMagick++ based applications check the local directory for dlls

Tags: c++, dll, deployment, imagemagick

I'm creating an application that uses ImageMagick++ to load and convert a sequence of pngs into gifs.

Everything works on my dev machine (unless I uninstall ImageMagick++), but it crashes on other users machines when it tries to use the gif and png coders.  I don't want end users to have to install ImageMagick in order to user the software.

It requires IM_MOD_RL_gif_.dll and IM_MOD_RL_png_.dll from the ImageMagick install directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16\modules\coders

It finds all the dlls and functions correctly when copied to the local directory except the coders.
Which don't work regardless of whether I copy them directly to the program directory. The following locations also failed (based off of advice I found elsewhere on the web).

applicationDir/
applicationDir/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/modules/coders
applicationDir/bin/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16/modules/coders
applicationDir/modules/coders

Is there anyway to make an application using ImageMagick++ check the local directory for coder dll's without having to rebuild ImageMagick++ myself?

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond here because I've seen a similar question unanswered elsewhere.

You just need to set the environment variable MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH for the process using the coders.